# Password protecting my app

Tags: android, button, crash, passwords

I am very new to JAVA and android development and am trying to password protect my app.
I have tried to make it so that whenever a user presses the submit button it will start a new activity if the password is correct.

so far i have the following code:

for my button:

```
 <Button
          android:id="@+id/button_enterpassword"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_below="@+id/text_enterpassword"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:layout_marginTop="262dp"
          android:onClick="openMenu"
          android:textSize="60sp"
          android:text="@string/button_confirm"
           />
```

for my activity:

```
 // This is the method called when the user presses the button 
public void openMenu(View view) {
    MyMethods compareText = new MyMethods();
    boolean same = compareText.compareText();
    if(same = true){ 
    MyMethods openActivity = new MyMethods();
    openActivity.callActivity();
    }
}}
```

for my MyMethods class:

```
 public class MyMethods extends Activity {

public void callActivity() {

     Intent intent = new Intent(this , MainMenu.class);
        startActivity(intent);
}

public boolean compareText() {
    boolean same = false;
    //assigning the name sumbitButton to the button from the UI
    //Button sumbitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_enterpassword);
    //Defines when the user has selected the button
   // sumbitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {        
        //public void onClick(View v){
        //assigning the name passwordEditText to the text inside the textbox
        EditText passwordEditText = (EditText)         

  findViewById(R.id.text_enterpassword);
        if(passwordEditText.getText().toString().equals("Test")){
            same = true;

        }
        return same;
        }

}
```

However whenever I press the button my program just crashes.

Cheers for your help!

Comment: You should post the error stack trace for better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of points to notice:

1. MyMethods is extending Activity, but the way you're using it is `unorthodox`.
2. In openMenu(), your comparison is wrong, you're missing one `=` in

   ```
   if (same = true) { //<---------- should be if (same == true) or if (same)
   ```
3. Remove your callActivity() and compareText() from MyMethods, and declare them in the class you will use them, that is in the class where you have openMenu(). I'd also rename compareText() to isPasswordValid(), to make it more clear.
4. Rewrite openMenu() to:

   ```
   public void openMenu(View view) {
       if (isPasswordValid()) {
           callActivity();
       }
   }
   ```
5. You can also rewrite compareText():

   ```
   public boolean isPasswordValid() {
       EditText passwordEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text_enterpassword);

       return passwordEditText.getText().toString().equals("Test");
   }
   ```
6. Also, since you're launching another activity, make sure it's declared in AndroidManifest.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! especially with what is and isn't orthodox!